# Sicilian Lowenthal-Labourdonnais

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, books, study

I am very interested in the Lowenthal Sicilian, specifically the 5. Nb5 a6 line:

1. e4 c5
2. Nf3 Nc6
3. d4 cxd4
4. Nxd4 e5 (signalling the Lowenthal)
5. Nb5 a6 (5 ... d6 is the Kalashnikov variation or what Silman refers to as the Neo-Sveshnikov)
6. Nd6+ Bxd6
7. Qxd6

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 e5 5. Nb5 a6 6. Nd6+ Bxd6 7. Qxd6
   ```

So variations begin here with ...Qe7 or ...Qf6

Now here is where my problem starts, I can not find a book on this line of the Sicilian for the life of me. It's a fairly popular line among GM's and strong players at my club. I really want to become well versed in it. I have studied a dozen or so GM games from the Lowenthal PGN file I downloaded from chess mentor but I learn much quicker from books where they explain white and black's long-term goals and strategies.

Can anybody recommend resources that will allow me to study this line?

Comment: Are you interested in playing this as White or Black?

Comment: I was looking at playing it for black. I have since gone through Aagaard's book on the kalashnikov and he covers it at the end.

Comment: Granted though not anywhere near the level of detail that I am interested in learning it.

Answer (score 2):

Any book covering the Open Sicilian from White's point of view should have a line against it. From memory White has a queen exchange, Qc7 or Qd1 in one of those variations.

EDIT: For starters try Dismantling the Sicilian by De La Villa. As stated above I recommend any complete repertoire book for White with the open Sicilian.

Comment: Downvoted because it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn to read better. It is an answer to the question "Can anybody recommend resources that will allow me to study this line?"

Comment: Ie any repertoire book for White on the Open Sicilian will cover the Lowenthal. I know you are strong enough to understand this.

Comment: So recommend some?

Comment: Any well regarded open sicilian book will do. I am sure the OP can search on google or amazon for open sicilian books.

Comment: OP mentionned in comments that he is interested in studying this line from Black's point of view. In that respect, a White repertoire which gives only one line for White is hardly enough.

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of the word any or the phrase "for starters". Any book will have a line on it, more than one book equals more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the book 'Dismantling the Sicilian", but it didn't satisfy my need of information. The best I can recommend is not a book. Simply use the analysis board of Chess.com and if you have premium, the opening book. There are also many master games which you can look at to learn about the strategies of this opening.